# MapView Pans when Annotation is Added

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

Is there a way to prevent my MKMapView from animating when I add a new annotation?

I have a number of annotations on my map that I'd like updated fairly regularly from an online API. As of now I simply remove all annotations and add back the new API results. However whenever any annotation is added the map automatically pans to them which is disorienting. The map should stay wherever the user currently has it positioned. Thank you.

Comment: The map view doesn't pan by default to the annotation added.  Does the code call setRegion, setVisibleMapRect, or setCenterCoordinate anywhere (such as in the didAddAnnotationViews delegate method)?

Comment: D'oh! You're right! I thought I looked for that but not well enough I guess!

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the region in my add annotations function. Face palm.